# How can I center truncate a string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Does anybody have any code handy that center truncates a string in Ruby on Rails?

Something like this:
Ex: "Hello World, how are you?" => "Hel...you?"

Comment: How many characters do you want to truncate ?

Comment: Using rails needs you to understand some intermediate programming topics and Ruby language. That's why I don't understand what is your problem -- it is really easy to implement. Some could argue about using helper, or monkey-patching `String` class, but *solving* is just plain easy.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is a modified version of Mike Woodhouse's answer. It takes 2 optional params: a minimum length for the the string to be ellipsisized and the edge length.

```
class String
  def ellipsisize(minimum_length=4,edge_length=3)
    return self if self.length < minimum_length or self.length <= edge_length*2 
    edge = '.'*edge_length    
    mid_length = self.length - edge_length*2
    gsub(/(#{edge}).{#{mid_length},}(#{edge})/, '\1...\2')
  end
end


"abc".ellipsisize #=> "abc"
"abcdefghi".ellipsisize #=> "abcdefghi"
"abcdefghij".ellipsisize #=> "abc...hij"
"abcdefghij".ellipsisize(4,4) #=> "abcd...ghij"
"Testing all paramas and checking them!".ellipsisize(6,5) #=> "Testi...them!"
```

Comment: Duh, I changed mine then noticed you'd done a more complete version. Nice. +1

Comment: May be we should submit it as a patch to Rails team?

Comment: Pretty complicated. See my answer for a much simpler solution utilizing existing Rails `String` helpers.

Comment: I added another solution combining Benjamin Sullivan's and khelll's. It uses built-in Rails stuff and lets you define edge length.

Answer (score 44):

If you want a certain fixed length irrespective of the length of the string, you can use Rails `#truncate`:

```
s.truncate(100, omission: "...#{s.last(50)}")
```

Comment: That's fantastic. Just what I was googling for.

Comment: You deserve my upvote. This is what I am looking for.

Comment: If the string is 110, for example, many characters will be repeated before and after the ellipsis

Comment: I don't observe repeated characters in Rails 5.1.

Answer (score 15):

How about a Regex version:

```
class String
  def ellipsisize
    gsub(/(...).{4,}(...)/, '\1...\2')
  end
end

"abc".ellipsisize #=> "abc"
"abcdefghi".ellipsisize #=> "abcdefghi"
"abcdefghij".ellipsisize #=> "abc...hij"
```

EDIT: as suggested in the comments, parameterised length (and using a different Regex notation, just for the heck of it)

```
class String
  def ellipsisize(len = 9)
    len = 9 unless len > 9 # assumes minimum chars at each end = 3
    gsub(%r{(...).{#{len-5},}(...)}, '\1...\2')
  end
end
```

so...

```
"abcdefghij".ellipsisize #=> "abc...hij"
```

but we can also:

```
"abcdefghij".ellipsisize(10) #=> "abcdefghij"
```

Comment: This solves the issues with both DigitalRoss's and JG's solutions. +1

Comment: Very nice, though I would have upvoted it just for the name of the method.

Comment: Cool, though it's gonna be better if you can modify it to accept string length parameter to apply the truncate only if the string is longer than that length.

Comment: Does this work with sending in non-3 argument with longer string for you? It doesn't for me, e.g. 'sadasdfafsdfdsfdasafsd'.ellipsisize(13)
 => "sad...fsd"

Answer (score 5):

Since you didn't specify how many characters you want to truncate, I'll assume (from your example) that you want to truncate strings whose length is greater than six. You can then use something like this:

```
s = "Hello World, how are you?"
s = s[0, 3] + "..." + s[-3, 3] if s.length > 9
=> "Hel...ou?"
```

Just adapt the ranges if you need to truncate more characters.

Comment: DigitalRoss is right about the "> 9" instead of "> 6" -- if you have a String of length 7 then you've added two characters _and_ lost information.

Comment: You are right, forgot to count the size of the ellipsis. It's fixed now.

Answer (score 5):

Here is my suggestion:

```
s[3...-4] = "..." if s.length > 9
```

Comment: I don't really like the editing-in-place since you don't know where the string is coming from. What if it's a model attribute and you later call save?

Comment: Yes, `(s=s.dup)[3...-4] = ...`  might be better, and even functional in a "as a black box" viewpoint. Good point.

Comment: You probably meant (t=s.dup)... there

Comment: Not really, it avoids modifying the underlying object, and now s is a reference to the new object. Now, if s was really thing.s, OK, now I agree with you, bad idea.

Comment: That is, it makes no difference which reference we assign to the object.  s="abc";q=s;s[1]='x';q => "axc" # so we might as well reuse s

Answer (score 3):

```
class String
  # https://gist.github.com/1168961
  # remove middle from strings exceeding max length.
  def ellipsize(options={})
    max = options[:max] || 40
    delimiter = options[:delimiter] || "..."
    return self if self.size <= max
    remainder = max - delimiter.size
    offset = remainder / 2
    (self[0,offset + (remainder.odd? ? 1 : 0)].to_s + delimiter + self[-offset,offset].to_s)[0,max].to_s
  end unless defined? ellipsize
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way:

```
class String
  def middle_truncate(len)
    return self if len >= size
    return self[0...len] unless len > 4
    half = len / 2.0
    (result = dup)[(half - 1.5).floor...(1.5 - half).floor] = '...'
    result
  end
end
```

This has the added benefit of just truncating if string size < 5.

e.g. for an even-sized string:

```
2.1.1 :001 > s = "12345678901234567890"
 => "12345678901234567890" 
2.1.1 :002 > s.middle_truncate 21
 => "12345678901234567890" 
2.1.1 :003 > s.middle_truncate 20
 => "12345678901234567890" 
2.1.1 :004 > s.middle_truncate 19
 => "12345678...34567890" 
2.1.1 :005 > s.middle_truncate 18
 => "1234567...34567890" 
2.1.1 :006 > s.middle_truncate 5
 => "1...0" 
2.1.1 :007 > s.middle_truncate 4
 => "1234"
```

and for an odd-sized string:

```
2.1.1 :012 > s = "123456789012345678901"
 => "123456789012345678901" 
2.1.1 :013 > s.middle_truncate 22
 => "123456789012345678901" 
2.1.1 :014 > s.middle_truncate 21
 => "123456789012345678901" 
2.1.1 :015 > s.middle_truncate 20
 => "12345678...345678901" 
2.1.1 :016 > s.middle_truncate 19
 => "12345678...45678901" 
2.1.1 :017 > s.middle_truncate 5
 => "1...1" 
2.1.1 :018 > s.middle_truncate 4
 => "1234"
```

Answer (score 2):

Modified rails version that only truncated from the middle

```rb
def middle_truncate(str, total: 30, lead: 15, trail: 15)
  str.truncate(total, omission: "#{str.first(lead)}...#{str.last(trail)}")
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I added position option to grosser's method:

```
def ellipsize(str, options={})
  max = options[:max] || 40
  delimiter = options[:delimiter] || "..."
  position =  options[:position] || 0.8
  return str if str.size <= max
  remainder = max - delimiter.size
  offset_left = remainder * position
  offset_right = remainder * (1 - position)
  (str[0,offset_left + (remainder.odd? ? 1 : 0)].to_s + delimiter + str[-offset_right,offset_right].to_s)[0,max].to_s
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to limit your string length by bytesize and you need to handle unicode then the solutions listed won't work correctly.

Here's a solution that uses byte size and keeps unicode *text elements* intact (which are not always the same as unicode *characters*).  Tested in Ruby 1.8/1.9/2.0.

It could be improved to be more efficient for very long strings that need to be truncated down to much smaller lengths.

You must install the unicode gem.

```
require 'unicode'

# truncates a unicode string like:
#   >> truncate_string_middle('12345678', 5)
#   => "1...8"
def truncate_string_middle(str, limit, ellipsis='...')
  raise "limit (#{limit}) must not be less than the ellipsis size (#{ellipsis.bytesize})" if limit < ellipsis.bytesize

  return str if str.bytesize <= limit

  chars = Unicode.text_elements(str)
  split_point = (chars.size/2.0).ceil
  front, back = chars[0...split_point], chars[split_point..-1]

  pop_front = chars.size.odd?
  # alternate between popping from the front and shifting from the back until it's small enough
  while (front.join + ellipsis + back.join).bytesize > limit
    if pop_front
      front.pop
    else
      back.shift
    end
    pop_front = !pop_front
  end

  front.join + ellipsis + back.join
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the easiest way for me:

```
def ellipsisize(text, minimum_length=12,edge_length=4)
  leftover = text.length - minimum_length
  edge_length = leftover if (edge_length > leftover && leftover >= 0)
  edge_length = 0 if leftover < 0

  return text.truncate(minimum_length) << text.last(edge_length)
end
```

Regards folks!

Answer (score 0):

A combination of Benjamin Sullivan's and khelll's answers. Uses built-in Rails stuff and lets you define edge length.

With `String#truncate`, I don't think there's a need to define minimum length at all. This solution automatically shortens the string if the shortened version is shorter than the input string.

```
def ellipsize(string, edge_length, separator: '…')
  string.truncate(
    edge_length * 2 + separator.size, omission: "#{separator}#{string.last(edge_length)}"
  )
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my version that lets you specify the maximum length instead, so, you can ensure that a string doesn't exceed the required length:

```rb
class String
    def truncate(maximum_length = 3, separator = '…')
        return '' if maximum_length.zero?
        return self if self.length <= maximum_length

        middle_length = self.length - maximum_length + separator.length
        edges_length = (self.length - middle_length) / 2.0
        left_length = edges_length.ceil
        right_length = edges_length.floor

        left_string = left_length.zero? ? '' : self[0, left_length]
        right_string = right_length.zero? ? '' : self[-right_length, right_length]

        return "#{left_string}#{separator}#{right_string}"
    end
end
```

```rb
'123456'.truncate(0) # ""
'123456'.truncate(1) # "…"
'123456'.truncate(2) # "1…"
'123456'.truncate(3) # "1…6"
'123456'.truncate(4) # "12…6"
'123456'.truncate(5) # "12…56"
'123456'.truncate(6) # "123456"
'123456'.truncate(7) # "123456"
```